# Writing to the InstalledLocation folder

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp

My Windows Store app fails certification because I'm writing the the InstalledLocation folder rather than the Local Folder.

I am loading an existing SQLite db in to the app if it doesn't already exist.

Below is my code:

```
    private static string dbName = "flashcards2015a.db";
    private static string dbPath = string.Empty;

public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        LoadDataTask();
        LoadDecksNames();
    }
    private async void LoadDataTask()
    {
        await CreateIfNotExists(dbName);
    }
    private async Task CreateIfNotExists(string dbName)
    {
        if (await GetIfFileExistsAsync(dbName) == null)
        {
            StorageFile seedFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, dbName));
            await seedFile.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
    }
```

How can I change the code to the Local Folder to get the db File?

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? The code you show doesn't write to the install location. It appears to correctly copy the seed database from the install location to local storage. Where it goes wrong is that it doesn't await LoadDataTask, so LoadDecksNames likely gets called before LoadDataTask has copied the file. Without knowing what LoadDecksNames does I don't know if it falls back to the seed or runs into some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Path.CombinWindows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path in StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync to Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync().

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322(v=win.10)

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///images/logo.png");
var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```